# Indentation significant syntax

Tags: compiler-construction, lua, metalua

I'm looking for a way to enable white space significant indentation in Lua, like in the OCaml/F#/Python languages (it really hurts me to put `end` keywords everywhere...).

Have someone managed to do it? Maybe with [metalua](http://metalua.luaforge.net/src/index.html)? Thanks!

Comment: As much as I prefer my languages to include this features, I don't think it's worth introducing complete and utter syntactic incompability with every single line of (non-trivial) code ever written. Think hard if it is for you.

Comment: @delnan: sure I think I could get used to it. I'm just curious if someone have managed to enable this (e.g. with metalua) and if it is worth the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [this Metalua example (pythonic)](http://metalua.luaforge.net/src/samples/pythonic.lua.html) is exactly what you are looking for.

Note that although Metalua allows you to modify Lua syntax, it does not work with LuaJIT.